# How do I improve my extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written an extension method which finds a control depending on the Type passed as an indexer to the function. Here is my extension method.

```
public static T FindControlByType<T>(this Control childCnt, string Id = "")
    {
        foreach (Control item in childCnt.Controls)
        {
            if (item is T)
            {
                if (Id == "")
                {
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));
                }
                if (item.ID.Contains(Id))
                {
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));
                }
            }
        }

        //return T 

    }
```

I want to return control of Type T. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a generic constraint to restrict `T` to be of type `Control`, then you don't need the `ChangeType` calls. The cast is enough.

```
public static T FindControlByType<T>(this Control childCnt, string id = "") 
    where T : Control
{ 
    foreach (Control item in childCnt.Controls) 
    { 
        if (item is T && ((id == "" || item.ID.Contains(id)))
        { 
            return (T)item; 
        } 
    } 

    return default(T);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Instead of returning default(T) i.e null when cnt is nt found Cant i return the same type i.e typeOf(T) control

Comment: No, because `typeof(T)` is an instance of the type `System.Type`, and you need to return an instance of the type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing i found is there is no need of

```
 if (Id == "")                 
  {                     
       return (T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));                 
  }
```

because every control in Asp.net Must have id.

Why dont you try oftype method of linq as below....(this is just suggestion)

```
var checkBoxes = this.GetAllControls().OfType<CheckBox>();
```

Comment: Id is an optional parameter. Its upto the user whether he wants to pass it or not

Comment: The if condition is checking the Id parameter of the method, not the Id property of the Control.

Comment: I think `Id` may or may not be passed, so believe this should be there

Comment: This is an extension method. Cant use this - this.GetAllControls()

Comment: @Ulhas Tuscano - you dont have to use that over all idea is make use ofType method.................

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are Converting the value if you have already validated that it `is T`.

This should be equivalent:

```
public static T FindControlByType<T>(this Control childCnt, string Id = "")
     where T: Control
{
    return childCnt.Controls.OfType<T>()
                   .FirstOrDefault(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id) || item.ID.Contains(Id));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Instead of returning default(T) i.e null when cnt is nt found Cant i return the same type i.e typeOf(T) control

Comment: No.  `typeof(T)` is `System.Type` object.  `T` in this instance is a `Control` object.  You cannot return a `System.Type` instance when the method expects a `Control` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be enough:

```
public static T FindControlByType<T>(this Control child, string id="") where T: Control
{
    return child.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Contains(id));    
}
```

By the way, are you sure you want to use `x.ID.Contains(id)`? Why?

If `ID="indians"` and `id="indian"`, then `ID.Contains(id)` would return `true`, even though `ID` and `id` are not same. If they're not same, what is the point of comparing them, and pretending that they're same?

I think you should use `x.ID.Equals(id)`:

```
return child.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(id));
```

Answer (score 1):

If this method is really for finding child `Control`s by type and not so much by `ID`*, you might consider returning `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `T`.  The method could then be easily implemented using Linq:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindControlsByType<T>(this Control childCnt, string Id = "")
    where T : Control
{
    var controls = childCnt.Controls.OfType<T>();

    return Id == "" ? controls : controls.Where(c => c.ID.Contains(Id));
}
```

Also, as others have pointed out, add a type constraint for the `T` type parameter.

* For that maybe the [FindControl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) already does what you need?  Note, though, that will search for an exact `ID` rather than a substring.